# Interpolation considering acceleration

Tags: math, physics

I don't really know if what I want to do is considered interpolation but I'll try to explain.

Now when I want to go from point `A` to point `B`(for simplicity consider only 1 coordinate space) in time `T` I compute position using linear interpolation formula:

```
P(t) = A + (B-A) * (t / T), T != 0
```

This works fine in most cases, but I want to cosider acceleration and braking like this:

- first `x%` of the time it will be acceleration from `vi` speed to `v` speed
- next `y%` of the time it will be constant `v` speed
- last `z%` of the time it will be deceleration to reach `vf` speed at `t = T`

How can I compute `P(t)`, `t` in `[0, T]` considering acceleration and braking?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.  But there are [simple equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration) for the position of an object undergoing constant acceleration.

Comment: You can derive the position formula by integrating the force equation twice and taking into account the necessary boundary conditions.

Comment: An alternative to the answer I posted below is using hermite interpolation. For this you specify start and end points and their tangents. I am not sure if this is what you need because there is no movement at constant speed involved, but you might want to have a look at it. It is definitely easier to implement.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math/physics rather than programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider we have the following points in time:

```
t0 = 0 is the beginning of the movement
ta is the point when acceleration ends
td is the point when decceleration begins
T is the end of the movement
```

Then we have three segments of the movement. `[t0, ta], (ta, td], (td, T]`. Each can be specified separately. For the acceleration / decceleration we need to calculate the acceleration `aa` and the decceleration `ad` as follows:

```
aa = (v - vi) / (ta - t0)
ad = (vf - v) / (T - td)
```

According to your question, all values are given.

Then the movement can be expressed as:

```
P(t) :=
    if(t < ta)
        1 / 2 * aa * t^2 + vi * t + A
    else if(t < td)
        v * (t - ta) + 1 / 2 * aa * ta^2 + vi * ta + A
                    // this is the length of the first part
    else
        1 / 2 * ad * (t - td)^2 + v * (t - td) 
          + v * (td - ta) + 1 / 2 * aa * ta^2 + vi * ta + A
          //those are the lengths of the first two parts
```

If we precompute the lengths of the parts as

```
s1 := 1 / 2 * aa * ta^2 + vi * ta + A
s2 := v * (td - ta)
```

then the formula becomes a bit shorter:

```
P(t) :=
    if(t < ta)
        1 / 2 * aa * t^2 + vi * t + A
    else if(t < td)
        v * (t - ta) + s1
    else
        1 / 2 * ad * (t - td)^2 + v * (t - td) + s1 + s2
```

Here is an example plot:

[image: Example]

However, it is very likely that the movement does not hit `B` at `T` except you chose proper values. That is because the equation is over-specified. You can e.g. calculate `v` based on B instead of specifying it.

### Edit

The calculation of `v` to reach a specific `B` is:

```
v = (2 * A - 2 * B - td * vf + T * vf + ta * vi) / (ta - td - T)
```